# Java ArrayList to store user input and terminate when -999 is entered

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been working on a java program with an arrayList that takes user input (double)  but terminates when the user enters -999. I have tried various while loops and keep getting errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Size;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for user input

        double a = -999;

        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();   

        System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {                       
            inputs.add(in.nextDouble()); }

        if (in != a)
            System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
        else{
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What errors are you getting?

Comment: `in` is a Scanner variable, and to check if the Scanner object == -999 doesn't make sense. You need to get input from the Scanner, assign it into a variable, and then test that variable. But this is best learned through reading any tutorial on how to use a Scanner. You would be advised to do this.

Comment: How are you entering you numbers: all on one line of one at a time?

Comment: ` if (in != a)` will not compile at all . also else part too ...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare a scanner to a double with `if(in != a)` you should assign the next double to a variable and then test it.

```
double Size;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for user input
double a = -999;
ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();
System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    //assign the nextDouble to a variable
    double tmp = in.nextDouble();
    //test the variable
    if(tmp!=a){
         //add the variable
         //if you want to add -999 to the inputs then this next line above the test.
         inputs.add(tmp);
         System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
    }
    else {
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to declare the variable tmp outside the loop to be able to calculate the how many numbers entered by user, the compiler msg says it has already been initialized. Any suggestion?

Comment: @orlagh `tmp` is a temporary double variable that holds the double entered by the user and is limited to the scope of the while loop. If you need to know how many inputs there are you can always use `inputs.size()`

Answer (score 0):

"in" is a Scanner, and a is a double. When you apply the != operator, a is converted to a Double. Since Scanner != Double is always true, you keep looping.

You want to retrieve the value from the scanner and convert it to a double. Then, you want to compare that value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Size;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner object for user input

        double a = -999;

        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();   

        System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {  
            double tmp=in.nextDouble();
            inputs.add(tmp); 

            if (tmp!=a)
             System.out.println("Enter a number, to terminate enter -999 :");
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your code corrected.
you had put a `}` in the wrong place in the while statement.
moreover i suggest to use a temporary variable (`tmp`) to read the values.
that way you can use `tmp` without problems.